# variantOutput.getPackageApplication() is obsolete

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, deprecation-warning, build-variant

with Gradle `4.10.1` and the Android Gradle plugin updated to `3.3.0`, I get the following warning:

> WARNING: API '`variantOutput.getPackageApplication()`' is obsolete and has been replaced with '`variant.getPackageApplicationProvider()`'.

the line, with the surrounding context (which is assigning output file-names by build variant):

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all { output ->

        if (variant.getBuildType().getName() in rootProject.archiveBuildTypes) {

            def buildType = variant.getBuildType().getName()
            if (variant.versionName != null) {

                def baseName = output.baseName.toLowerCase()
                String fileName = "${rootProject.name}_${variant.versionName}-${baseName}.apk"

                // this is the line:
                outputFileName = new File(output.outputFile.parent, fileName).getName()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the [migration guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/task_configuration_avoidance.html) isn't too helpful; while the `variant.outputs.all` might be at fault - just have no clue with what to replace that - and the migration guide refers to tasks and not to build variants. when disabling `File → Settings → Experimental → Gradle → Only sync the active variant`, I get even more deprecation warnings (the point is, that none of these methods are being called directly):

```
WARNING: API 'variant.getAssemble()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getAssembleProvider()'.
WARNING: API 'variantOutput.getProcessResources()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variantOutput.getProcessResourcesProvider()'.
WARNING: API 'variantOutput.getProcessManifest()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variantOutput.getProcessManifestProvider()'.
WARNING: API 'variant.getMergeResources()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getMergeResourcesProvider()'.
WARNING: API 'variant.getMergeAssets()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getMergeAssetsProvider()'.
WARNING: API 'variant.getPackageApplication()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getPackageApplicationProvider()'.
WARNING: API 'variant.getExternalNativeBuildTasks()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getExternalNativeBuildProviders()'.
WARNING: API 'variantOutput.getPackageApplication()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getPackageApplicationProvider()'.
```

Q: how can these deprecation warnings be avoided by migration to the new API?

Comment: `output.outputFile.parent` => `variant.getPackageApplicationProvider().get().outputs.files[1]` .... google should fix it because the problem is `output.outputFile` it's internally calling `getPackageApplication()`

Comment: @Selvin this at least fixes the one warning; while then it complains: `variant.getExternalNativeBuildTasks()` is obsolete... which would need to be replaced with `variant.getExternalNativeBuildProviders()`

Comment: hehe `variant.getExternalNativeBuildProviders()` this comes from  .... let me guess ... io.fabric plugin ...

Comment: @Selvin you are correct; with debug enabled this hints for: `com.crashlytics.tools.gradle.ProjectVariantState.resolveDebugNativeLibsPath(ProjectVariantState.groovy:130)`. add the comment as an answer and I'd accept it, because it answers the primary question.

Comment: So ... it's all Google's fault ... same as `registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)` from `com.google.gms.google-services` ... I give up with this ... I spent 2 days analyzing those warnings

Comment: @Selvin I got used to ignore this one warning. but when the warnings get too many, at some point it becomes unclear, within who's responsibility they would be.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a good answer `variant.getPackageApplicationProvider().get().outputs.files[1]` doesnt looks good ... also `variant.getPackageApplicationProvider().get().outputs.files[0]` points to `build\intermediates\incremental\packageVariant1Varian2...` ... what if Google change 0 with 1 in next release? ... there should be easy way to get path to apk from either assemble or package task

Comment: once Gradle 5.x will become the default, a whole lot more will break. most workarounds might only be temporary solutions. just found out that `android.enableSeparateAnnotationProcessing = true` fixes one incremental annotation processor warning for `Room`.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/known-issues ... "tasks that involve accessing `outputFile` objects no longer work. That's because variant-specific tasks are no longer created during the configuration stage. This results in the plugin not knowing all of its outputs up front, but it also means faster configuration times."

Comment: @Selvin I've just found a workaround for the `registerResGeneratingTask()`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*variantOutput.getPackageApplication()* is being caused by a changed variant API.

> changing `output.outputFile.parent` to `variant.getPackageApplicationProvider().get().outputs.files[1]` is at least a temporary workaround.

source: [@Selvin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/690952/selvin).

---

*variant.getExternalNativeBuildTasks()* is being caused by the `io.fabric` plugin.

> the next version of the `io.fabric` plugin will use `variant.getExternalNativeBuildProviders()`.

source: [116408637](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/116408637); the [confirmation](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/198#issuecomment-456455002) for a promised fix (`1.28.1`).

---

These are caused by `com.google.gms.google-services`:

- `registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)`
- `'variant.getMergeResources()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getMergeResourcesProvider()'`

This [blog post](https://medium.com/@samstern_58566/how-to-use-firebase-on-android-without-the-google-services-plugin-93ecc7dc6c4) explains how to get rid of the `com.google.gms.google-services` plugin altogether, by adding the XML resources, which that plugin generates, eg. from `build/generated/res/google-services/debug/values/values.xml` into the regular `debug/values/values.xml`.

---

The most easy and the least effort might be:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven { url "https://maven.fabric.io/public" }
    }
    dependencies {
        //noinspection GradleDependency
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1"
        classpath "io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.28.1"
    }
}
```

---

For debug information: `./gradlew -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true  mobile:assembleDebug`

None of these `warnings` changes the behavior in any way.

Comment: I guess it's related to their plugins, and we can not really do anything.

Comment: in my case it was `dexcount gradle` plugin. After I upgraded it to version `0.8.6` warning is gone.

Comment: @IlyaEremin there may be various plugins still using these methods.

Comment: @@martim zeitler. I have the same issue but I'm not using fabric plugin

Comment: @Ggriffo then likely it's some other plugin using that deprecated API.

Answer (score 9):

Update Fabric gradle plugin to **1.28.1**

```
dependencies {
   classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.28.1'
}
```

Changelog:
https://docs.fabric.io/android/changelog.html#march-15-2019

> Eliminated obsolete API warnings by switching to Gradle’s task configuration avoidance APIs, when available.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the simpler one, similar to this example:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.all { output ->
                outputFileName = "${globalScope.project.name}-${variant.versionName}_${output.baseName}.apk"
            }
        }
```

and the result would be `my_app-1.9.8_flavor1-release.apk`.

In your code the problematic part (that generate the warning) is `output.outputFile`:

```
..
outputFileName = new File(output.outputFile.parent, fileName).getName()
..
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `output.outputFile` is internally calling `getPackageApplication()`

I solved this problem by setting the directory and name of the output file myself.

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        def outputDir = new File("${project.buildDir.absolutePath}/outputs/apk/${variant.flavorName}/${variant.buildType.name}")
        def outputFileName = "app-${variant.flavorName}-${variant.buildType.name}.apk"
        // def outputFile = new File("$outputDir/$outputFileName")

        variant.packageApplicationProvider.get().outputDirectory = new File("$outputDir")
        output.outputFileName = outputFileName
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So I was getting the same issue (as of this date, running Gradle 5.4.1). Furthermore, I didn't see an answer that effectively covered both application projects as well as library projects.

Thus, I wanted to make something that could theoretically be used on any project to make a single build.gradle for the whole project, if desired. Because it turned out quite well, I figured I'd add it in case someone wants something that will work for both application and library projects.

## Edit:

I have updated/optimized this method since originally posting it. I am now using gradle 6.3 with Kotlin DSL and the following works swimmingly.

## Edit2:

It seems somewhere in Android Gradle build tools 4.1.0 (beta) that they disabled build config generation for library projects by default, so I had to change one line to accept a null value with a backup, updated below.

```kotlin
/**
 * Configures the output file names for all outputs of the provided variant. That is, for
 * the provided application or library.
 *
 * @param variant Passed in with {android.defaultConfig.applicationVariants.all.this}
 * @param project The project from which to grab the filename. Tip: Use rootProject
 * @param formatString Format string for the filename, which will be called with three 
 * arguments: (1) Project Name, (2) Version Name, (3) Build Type. ".apk" or ".aar" is 
 * automatically appended. If not provided, defaults to "%1$s-%2$s_%3$s"
 */
@SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryQualifiedReference")
fun configureOutputFileName(
    variant: com.android.build.gradle.api.BaseVariant,
    project: Project,
    formatString: String = "%1\$s-%2\$s_%3\$s"
) {
    variant.outputs.configureEach {
        val fileName = formatString.format(project.name,
            outputVariant.generateBuildConfigProvider.orNull?.versionName?.orNull ?:
                project.version, variant.buildType.name)
        val tmpOutputFile: File = when (variant) {
            is com.android.build.gradle.api.ApplicationVariant -> 
                File(variant.packageApplicationProvider!!.get().outputDirectory.asFile
                    .get().absolutePath,"$fileName.apk")
            is com.android.build.gradle.api.LibraryVariant -> 
                File(variant.packageLibraryProvider!!.get().destinationDirectory.asFile
                    .get().absolutePath,"$fileName.aar")
            else -> outputFile
        }
        (this as com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.BaseVariantOutputImpl)
            .outputFileName = tmpOutputFile.name
        println("Output file set to \"${tmpOutputFile.canonicalPath}\"")
    }
}
```

---

#### Original:

The relevant part is here.

```java
android {
    if (it instanceof com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension) {
        it.applicationVariants.all { 
            com.android.build.gradle.api.ApplicationVariant variant ->
                configureOutputFileName(variant, project)
        }
    } else if (it instanceof com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension) {
        it.libraryVariants.all { com.android.build.gradle.api.LibraryVariant variant ->
            configureOutputFileName(variant, project)
        }
    }
}
```

Which simply calls the method below.

```java
@SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryQualifiedReference")
private void configureOutputFileName(com.android.build.gradle.api.BaseVariant variant,
    Project project) {
    variant.outputs.all { output ->
        def buildType = variant.buildType.name
        String tmpOutputFileName = outputFileName
        if (variant instanceof com.android.build.gradle.api.ApplicationVariant) {
            String fileName = "${project.name}-${variant.versionName}_${buildType}.apk"
            def defaultOutputDir = variant.packageApplicationProvider.get().outputDirectory
            tmpOutputFileName = new File(defaultOutputDir.absolutePath, fileName).name
        }
        if (variant instanceof com.android.build.gradle.api.LibraryVariant) {
            String fileName = "${project.name}_${buildType}.aar"
            def defaultOutputDir = variant.packageLibraryProvider.get()
                .destinationDirectory.asFile.get()
            tmpOutputFileName = new File(defaultOutputDir.absolutePath, fileName).name
        }
        println(tmpOutputFileName)
        outputFileName = tmpOutputFileName
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't using `output.outputFile.parent`in my gradle. The cause for `variantOutput.getPackageApplication()` obsolete warning was the dex count plugin. I updated it to 0.8.6 and warning is gone.

```
'com.getkeepsafe.dexcount:dexcount-gradle-plugin:0.8.6'
```

Answer (score 0):

The culprit of below warning is **`output.outputFile`**

> WARNING: API 'variantOutput.getPackageApplication()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getPackageApplicationProvider()'.

To get rid of this warning for Android Gradle plugin **3.4.0+**, you can manually assemble the output path as below:

```
def selfAssembledOutputPath = new File("${project.buildDir.absolutePath}/outputs/apk/${variant.flavorName}/${variant.buildType.name}")
```

Then replace your below line with `selfAssembledOutputPath` defined above

```
// this is the line:
outputFileName = selfAssembledOutputPath
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit less dodgy solution:

```
def variant = findYourVariantSomehow()
def output = findCorrectOutputInVariant(variant)
def fileName = output.outputFileName

def fileDir = variant.packageApplicationProvider.get().outputDirectory.get()

def apkFile = file("$fileDir/$fileName")
```

[source](https://qiita.com/kasa_le/items/e2682235db901032f00c)

Answer (score -1):

I used to wirite like this:

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    if ("release" == variant.buildType.name) {
        variant.outputs.all { output ->
            outputFileName = output.outputFile.name.replace("-release", "")
        }
        variant.assemble.doLast {
            variant.outputs.all { output ->
                delete output.outputFile.parent + "/output.json"
                copy {
                    from output.outputFile.parent
                    into output.outputFile.parentFile.parent
                }
                delete output.outputFile.parent
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The warning pop up each time, like open AS,sync,clean...

Then I found a way to write , it will just appear in build but will not pop up each time.

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    if ("release" == variant.buildType.name) {
        assembleRelease.doLast {
            variant.outputs.all { output ->
                delete output.outputFile.parent + "/output.json"
                copy {
                    from output.outputFile.parent
                    into output.outputFile.parentFile.parent
                    rename { filename ->
                        filename.replace("-release", "")
                    }
                }
                delete output.outputFile.parent
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you just don't want the warning pop each time, these may have some tips for you.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use an older version of gradle. I changed my gradle version from 3.5.0 to 3.2.1 and it worked.[image]

Comment: This merely depends on the Gradle version. Meanwhile have it working with little warnings, with the latest Fabric & Google Play Services plug-ins.