# API 'variant.getJavaCompile()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getJavaCompileProvider()'. It will be removed at the end of 2019

Tags: android, android-studio, objectbox

**When i was add object plugIn It will show this warning..Any one know how should I solve this. Its bothering me at every time**

WARNING: API 'variant.getJavaCompile()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getJavaCompileProvider()'.
It will be removed at the end of 2019.
For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
To determine what is calling variant.getJavaCompile(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display a stack trace.
Affected Modules: app

Comment: Talk to the authors of "object plugin".

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/q/54206898/7666442

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed in the latest release of the Fabric gradle plugin, 1.28.0. Have this in your top-level build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
  // ... repositories, etc. ...

   dependencies {
       // ...other dependencies ...
       classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.28.0'
   }
}
```

Comment: I am using the newer one classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.29.0' but i am getting this error

Comment: Why not try to  1.28.0 version.

Comment: i have tried it but seems like its persistant ,  try to make a new project of a app in adroid studio now using the new firebase libs you will seee what i am saying .

Comment: what is your android studio version?

Comment: am using the latest  3.4.1

Comment: same version I used 1.28.0 version for gradle. I recommended that It is better to use 1.28.0.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195924/discussion-between-kinsley-kajiva-and-masum).

Comment: What is "Fabric gradle plugin"? I think the warning at my AS is from a Google library...

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem too but this is just a warning although it's a red message, and it's going to be fixed with plugin updates, you should not worry about it.

But if it's bothering you, you can downgrade your Gradle version to 3.2.0 and it will be disappeared.
*(I'm not sure about Gradle version but if 3.2.0 doesn't help you, try other versions).*

Answer (score 1):

As the message indicates it is a warning that can be safely ignored until you update to versions of Android Gradle Plugin beyond 3.3.0.

We are aware of this and a future update will use the new instead of the deprecated Android Gradle Plugin API.

https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-java/issues/643

Answer (score -1):

For my case, i used `variant.javaCompile()` in my gradle, change it to `variant.javaCompileProvider()`, and then the problem was solved.

So you can try to change `variant.javaCompile()` to `variant.javaCompileProvider()` in your code.

Or check the gradle plugin you used, for example Fabric.

Comment: variant.javaCompile() does not come up in any search in my code

Comment: @Jordan check the plugin that was included in your gradle

Comment: What plugin? And what could you do about problems in 3rd party code (if you even have the code and not only a pre-compiled library)?