# Gradle Build Error in Gradle Plugin 3.6.1, Distribution URL version 5.6.4

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am getting this error when building my project

`groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFilePropertyFactory$DefaultDirectoryVar.toPath() is applicable for argument types: () values: []`

my gradle script looks like this

`newApkName = "${appName}${separator}${output.baseName}${separator}${variant.versionName}.apk" def relativeRootDir = output.packageApplication.outputDirectory.toPath() .relativize(rootDir.toPath()).toFile()`

it seems the toPath() method signature has changed. please help

Comment: it would be nice if these breaking changes were documented somewhere

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by following [Chris Parker's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56164030/150978) in this issue: [variantOutput.getPackageApplication() is obsolete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54206898/variantoutput-getpackageapplication-is-obsolete)