# intellij idea error while building android project - groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, groovy, build.gradle

Trying to build Android project in intellij idea and getting following error:
Build file 'C:\Users...\app\build.gradle' line: 91

A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFilePropertyFactory$DefaultDirectoryVar.toPath() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
>     Possible solutions: each(groovy.lang.Closure), tap(groovy.lang.Closure), with(groovy.lang.Closure), with(boolean, groovy.lang.Closure), getAt(java.lang.String), putAt(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object)

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        def project = "Demo"
        def flavourName = variant.flavorName
        def variantName = "Build"
        def apkName = project + "-" + flavourName + "-" + variantName + "-" + versionName + ".apk"
        def relativeRootDir = variant.packageApplicationProvider.get().outputDirectory.toPath()
                .relativize(rootDir.toPath()).toFile()    // <-- error line   
        output.outputFileName = new File("$relativeRootDir/release", apkName)
    }
}
```

How to solve this? what should I change?

Comment: Check this [Gradle discussion thread](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/gradle-build-error-in-plugin-3-6-1-and-distribution-url-5-6-4/35328) which leads to the suggestion here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56164030/2000323

Comment: @Andrey this was right. it resolved my issue.